# Bash - Display menu with network interfaces as options

Tags: linux, bash, network-interface

I am a total bash newbie, and I need to make a script that has a menu where each of the options is one of the available network interfaces of the system. The user must choose one of the options.

So basically, I am looking for something like this (when executed).

```
Please, select a network interface:

1)eth0
2)eth1
3)lo
```

And then the user can input 1, 2 or 3 to select one of those options.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll want to parse the output of `ifconfig` (the `-s` option may be helpful). Then use bash's `select` command to create the menu (hint: use `PS3` for the prompt). You should be able to search this site for examples of select.

Comment: look here how to use `select` http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html. the interfaces list you can get by `ifconfig -s | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: Thank you guys, definitely helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "Please, select a network interface:"
cd /sys/class/net && select foo in *; do echo $foo selected; done
```

Output:

```
Please, select a network interface:
1) eth0
2) lo
#?
```

See: `help select` and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203309/74329) example to see how to use `select` and `case`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cyrus. Tomorrow I'll give it a try and I'll be back to mark it as valid if it works :)